# Redirect WWW to one subfolder and wildcard to another htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to create work this Htaccess in a way that allows me to send www. to one subfolder and and any wildcard subdomains to another folder on a CentOS7 Linux server. The file structure is as follows as both subfolders have different php frameworks within them: -

- .htaccess
- cms (Yii)
- app (Symfony)

The Htaccess File I currently have (it's been chopped around a bit) currently looks like this: -

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/public/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/public/index.php?p=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(*.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/web/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/web/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(*.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ app/web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help of making this work would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you configure this in your virtualhosts?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre I'm not sure how to do this